# marginal plots in GBM

Tags: data-visualization, boosting

plot.gbm (...)

Description: plots the marginal effect of the selected variables by "intergrating" out the other variables.

could you please put it another way? the same meaning with "parital dependency"? The figure represents the increment of the variable on X-axis triggers the variation of reponse variable? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the partial dependence requires a few steps. First you select the covariate of interest, x. Then, create a grid of evenly spaced values from x-min to x-max. For every value in the grid loop through the entire dataset and calculate the predicted response.

The average of all predicted responses for each x-value *holding all other covariates constant* is what is meant by "integrating" out the other variables. This average response is what is plotted on the y-axis in the partial dependence plot.

Comment: all other covarate are kept at their mean value?

Comment: All other covariates are kept at their *observed* values. Every observation in the dataset is evaluated holding all values constant EXCEPT for the variable used in the partial dependence calculation. That variable is evaluated as many times as there are grid values. The change in response is recorded and then averaged across all of the grid values.

Comment: among "all other covariates", each covariate has many observed values. How can they be held at constant?

Comment: The values are fixed at their observed value per observation.

Comment: e.g., y=x1+x2+x3, x1 is the covariate of interest.    y, x1, x2, x3, each has 10 values. So, firstly, average y is calculated using all x1(1)~x1(10), meanwhile,x2(1) and x3(1) are held; secondly, average y is calculated again using all x1(1)~x1(10), meanwhile,x2(2) and x3(2) are held...correct?

Comment: Exacty right! You've got it.